# Is there a way to reuse the built-in HTML editor in Cofoundry

Tags: cofoundry

I would like to embed Cofoundry's built-in administration interface visual editor in other custom non-admin pages. The idea is not to use any of the fancy attributes like [HTML], but rather be able to load the editor using low level JavaScript and HTML instead of installing yet another editor myself and use that.

I suppose it is a standard HTML editor, so given the URLs for it in Cofoundry, I assume it would be possible to use the editor's own standard documentation for embedding the editor.

So, question, which editor is it - and what are the built-in URLs (paths) to it's components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v0.9 Cofoundry uses TinyMCE as the HTML editor. You'd be better off using your own build of the editor than linking to the Cofoundry source as it's liable to change.